# Unity3d Gravity script issues

Tags: physics, unity, planet

I'm try this script out

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Gravity

and I'm having some issues with it (it seemed to work when I tried it with an old version of unity)

the first issue is of collision, the objects (in my case spheres) will stick into each other rather than just touch.

and the second is that when the objects collide one of the objects with continue it's trajectory.

I'm thinking of rewriting the script from scratch unless someone can explain what's wrong with the script that i've got.

[image: Just two spheres]

Comment: Might be the Rigidbody Kinematic and Mass setting in you've got set, the continued trajectory sounds like the mass of the object is 0.

Comment: I have kinematic off, and the default gravity off too. but the force upon collision carries on and isn't lost.

Comment: In that screenshot gravity is set to 0, that'll be why.

Comment: no gravity has to be set to 0 for the script to work, that gravity is the inbuilt gravity setting of unity, all the planets will fall to the ground and that's not what i'm looking for.